# Is it effective for me to put the meta tag in the head in the body?

Tags: angular, seo, meta-tags

I use angular, I put the main meta tag at index.html.
In the subpages I also put the meta tag in the head inside the main body, will this work for SEO?
The generated html snippet looks like this:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>title 1</title>
    <meta name="description" content="content1">
</head>
<body class="mat-typography">
    <app-root _nghost-ng-c1032261643="" ng-version="16.1.3">
        <app-pages _ngcontent-ng-c1032261643="" _nghost-ng-c4253676475="">
            <html _ngcontent-ng-c4253676475="" lang="en">
            <head _ngcontent-ng-c4253676475="">
                <meta name="description" content="content_child">
            </head>
            <body _ngcontent-ng-c4253676475="">
            </body>
            </html>
        </app-pages>
    </app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Any idea please?